# Cleaning unwanted rows of a scrapy result

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data using Scrapy and and clean the result of price from any unwanted characters with mapcompose.

The result I have so far gives me a clean price, without any unwanted characters like currency sign or any . or , 
But, it gives me "extra" empty rows.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, Join
from makelaars.items import MakelaarsItem

class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'basic'
    allowed_domains = ['web']
    start_urls = ['https://www.bouka-makelaars.nl/koopaanbod']

    def parse(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=MakelaarsItem(), response=response)
        #Extracting the content using css selectors
        l.add_css('address', '.details.property-page-link > h2[class=address]::text')
        l.add_css('price', '.price::text',MapCompose(lambda i: i.replace('.', '')),re='[.0-9]+')

        return l.load_item()
```

The output I got so far is:

```
{'address': [u'Wezelrade 143 B',
             u'Wilhelmina van Pruisenlaan 245',
             u'Suzannaland 206',
             u'Molenweide 32',
             u'Spiraeastraat 00 2e etage',
             u'Kerklaan 122',
             u'Brandtstraat 163 /163A',
             u'Wouwermanstraat 9 /11/13/15',
             u'Scheepersstraat 100 /102/102A',
             u'Honthorststraat 137 /135',
             u'Brandtstraat 151 151A'],
 'price': [u'119500',
           u'',
           u'',
           u'200000',
           u'',
           u'',
           u'269500',
           u'',
           u'',
           u'539500',
           u'',
           u'',
           u'200000',
           u'',
           u'',
           u'299000',
           u'280000',
           u'',
           u'',
           u'675000',
           u'',
           u'',
           u'495000',
           u'',
           u'',
           u'475000',
           u'',
           u'',
           u'350000']}
```

Comment: Do you want to know how to remove those empty `u''` items by modifying how you extract content, or is it fine to just run a list comprehension over `price` in order to remove them. Also, you say "extra" empty rows, so does that mean you want one empty row between prices, or you want to remove all instances?

Comment: In the end I want to export the results to a CSV. The number of results in addresses are 11 in total, the results in price should be 11 too. I wild like to remove the ```u''``` indeed. I do not want the extra rows, it is something I want to get rid off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only need to clean the `prices` list before exporting the results to a CSV, you can do the following: 
(`output` is assumed to be the dict that contains what you've shown in the question)

```
output['price'] = [item for item in output['price'] if item]
# empty strings in python are considered False, while others are True
```

Your updated `output['price']` will be exactly `11` in length, as below:

```
['119500', '200000', '269500', '539500', '200000', '299000', '280000', '675000', '495000', '475000', '350000']
```